# Can I use PhoneGap to create and submit iBook

Tags: ios, submit, phonegap-build, ibooks

Apple has a habit of rejecting apps which they consider to be books and suggest submitting these kind of apps to their iBook store instead. Since I built an app with this problem using PhoneGap Build, I was wondering is it possible to submit a PhoneGap Build project to the iBook store and if so, how does one go about doing this? I've found very little information about this online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. PhoneGap is used to build iOS applications for the App Store -- iBooks doesn't support a UIWebView (or WKWebView), which is the main entrance to a PhoneGap application. You can build some HTML widgets for use in iBooks Author, but that's as far as you can go.